# When I integrate the PayPal SDK it prompt a error message "internal server error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I Add the library of PayPal SDK and add

`[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"XXXXXXXXX" forEnvironment:XXXXXX];`
 code then it give the error message "internal server Error"

Please provide me the step of in integration of PayPal.

There is no proper documentation of PayPal integration in iOS.In its sample code the parallel transaction going very smooth when i create a new project and add paypal library it gives an error.
In the sample code add -lxml2 in other linker library but In the documentation of PayPal there is no such things so I think something is missing in my project.

Comment: if you have answer or any type of hint then please share it and then downward my question.

Comment: I am also getting same error, anyone having answer please do comment.

Comment: I got the solution of that problem.please add "Bundle Display Name" in info.plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Bundle display name` in your info.plist of your project as an empty.

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I got the answer.

Comment: @suyashseth : can you please update your answer here along with question. so that one could try that out. Thanks.